# variables are not replaced in the parameters and assertion statements

Tags: karate

I have my below code

```
#create document type
* print 'create document type'
* def documentTypeNameValue = 'sum2'
* print documentTypeNameValue
* def result = call read('classpath:examples/commonResources/documentTypes/createDocumentType.feature') { X-CSRF-TOKEN: csrfToken, JSESSIONID: jsessionid, documentTypeName: documentTypeNameValue, inputFile: 'examples/commonResources/documentTypes/add2NumbersDoc.json'}
Then  match result.response.integration.message.description contains 'Success'

Then  match result.response.integration.serviceData.message contains '#(documentTypeNameValue)'  +' created successfully'
```

variable 'documentTypeNameValue' is printed properly in the print statement
but when i am trying to use the same variable while passing as parameter to feature file and during assetion statement this variable is not substituted with actual value('here it is sum2)

Please suggest some solution to substitute the variable value as parameters and also in assertion

I have also attached the screenshot for reference[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to understand. So I may not be able to help much.

2 things.

When there are hyphens in the JSON key, you need to use quotes else it is not valid JSON `{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '#(csrfToken)' }`

And you are not using embedded expressions where you need to.

And again you are making the same mistake, embedded expressions should be the entire RHS string value or JSON value.

You can do this instead (normal JS). Please read the docs carefully, especially the section on [Karate Expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions).

```
Then  match result.response.integration.serviceData.message contains documentTypeNameValue  + ' created successfully'
```

Comment: Hi peter, Thank you for reply. Detailed problem space is                      
 * def documentTypeName = "sum2"
* print documentTypeName
* def result = call read("some feature file called here");

Then  match result.response.integration.serviceData.message contains '#(documentTypeName)'  +' created successfully'

Comment: @Anupama huh ??

Comment: Variable name substituted properly in the print statement but not in the assertion statement.  i tried karate expression but did not any way to resolve issue. Hope I am clear now. Waiting for your valuable response. Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure you even read or tried to make changes to your JSON to use embedded expressions. this is the only valuable response I have left: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue | your `call` argument is wrong. all the best.